# How to run JS script which has import from npm-library on iPhone by Content View?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, npm, swiftui

I have this code and node_modules in shared folder in x code project. It have to show me text key generated from js-code. js-code works outside by node.js, but it shows me 'undefined' in Content View. Can I  import js modules in x code project? Will it work on iPhone?

```
//  ContentView.swift
//  Shared

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import JavaScriptCore

class Cube {
    func doJS(text: String) -> String? {
        let jsSource = "var testFunct = function test(message) { const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa'); const key = new NodeRSA(); var k = key.generateKeyPair(); var p = k.exportKey('pkcs1'); return p};"

        let context = JSContext()
        context?.evaluateScript(jsSource)

        let testFunction = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("testFunct")
        return testFunction?.call(withArguments: [text]).toString()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(Cube().doJS(text: "Hello, world!") ?? "No result")
            .fontWeight(.black)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
            .padding()
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

My js code:

```
// npm install node-rsa 
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa

var testFunct = function test(message) { 
    const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
    const key = new NodeRSA(); 
    var k = key.generateKeyPair(); 
    var p = k.exportKey('pkcs1'); 
    return p};
console.log(testFunct())
```

[image]

Comment: My suspicion is that you'll have to run a bundler on the JS code (something like Webpack, for example) so that you end up with *one* Javascript file that doesn't do `import` or `require`